# php file upload and directory permission

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions, chmod

I run my php application on VPS. In this application I have a feature where user upload files.

On the server php file upload works only if upload directory has `777` permission. Currently I am facing lot of hack and spamming issue due to `777` permissions to upload dir.

So I cant take a risk to keep the directories with `777` permissions. Please tell me some solution in this scenario.

I am curious to know how people handle sercure file upload and manage directory permissions? especially when server requires `777` permissions.

Comment: Would you like to share those issues due to spamming and hacking??

Comment: give your directory 644 or 755 permission

Comment: What type of files are uploaded to your server by users then??

Comment: In order to prevent users from hacking and spamming by uploading executable files or scripts make sure to allow specific format of files for uploading only..!

Comment: giving 644 or 755 permissions to dir it is not allowing to upload (from php code).. that is why I need solution..

Comment: All the emails sent from that specific domains were getting bounced back since the IP was getting blacklisted due to spamming.. my host did not find the spam script location .. he modified permissions to all dirs to make it secure.. but since 777 permission of upload dir is modified to 755 my php file upload script is not working

Comment: I have taken a care that the file uplaod script will allow only specific file types.. users are allowed to upload .pdf, .zip and image files only